# Browser Back Button Breaks on Some Pages

Tags: browser, back-button, bigcommerce

I'm working on an online store website and the browser Back Button works every time except during one circumstance:

When you're on a product category page and you sort the products ("Price: Low to High" for example). When you click on a product and are taken to a product page, if you try to click the Back Button in the browser it takes you to a broken page.

If you don't sort the products and go to a product page, then click the Back Button, it works fine!

This is the error messages. Chrome Error Message: "Confirm Form Resubmission" / IE Error Message: "Webpage has expired" / Firefox Error Message: "Document Expire"

Any ideas on a fix? Shopping cart software is BigCommerce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Confirm Form Resubmission" appears when you have submitted a form using `POST`, meaning you probably have something like this in the code: `<form method="post">`

Sorting should be better done using `GET` instead of `POST`. If you need further help provide us with the code responsible for sorting.

Comment: Good, if you think it is the right solution so far, mark it as the best answer.